# How to fix the issue of image cutout in swift 3?

Tags: swift3

I am sharing my image to iMessage using UIActivityViewController.
Here is my code.

```
...
var sharingItems = [AnyObject]()
sharingItems.append(self.imageView.image)
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
...
```

But I got the below result.
[image]

How can I fix?

Comment: imageView contentMode aspect fit

Comment: That's default Messages app in iPhone.
I am trying to share my image to iMessage or Mail.
How can I adjust another app?
I think it's not possible.